# why we use different extensions(Layouts) in node.js like handlebars,jade,ejs, etc?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, mean-stack, ejs

I'm a beginner to Nodejs. I'm developing MEAN Stack project for my University Project. so I have some questions regarding extensions in NodeJs.

What is the most suitable extension to use in nodejs projects?
Pros and Cons of the extension that you suggest?
Is it good to use .html extension than other extensions?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't considered a good question for Stack Overflow, read [How to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Noted dude.. I will go through the link that you provided .. have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

let me start by answering the last question first,

> Is it good to use .html extension than other extensions

like anything in the frontend world, it all depends on the application youre building, for a simple application for example, it might be easier and faster to just use html.

now, why would you choose to use an HTML "preprocessor".

There are many reasons, i have used `PUG` for a while in production, and used quiet a lot of templating engines in various projects.

1. nodeJS is considered a middleware / backend, its very difficult to send data from your server directly to HTML (you'd have to inject script containing a javascript object, or so). having a templating engine will solve this for you by having all the data you have in node for the preprocessor.
2. SEO, having a pre-rendered HTML with the full page content, instead of relying on javascript to fetch the data on the browser greatly increases your SEO rank, since lots of descriptive data can be lost as the bots might not run javascript on the page etc.
3. lots of templating engines offer similar features, the core differences might rely in the technique they implement their style of writing the HTML templates. i found `PUG` the most natural to write in for me, since you can directly write javascript inside and the syntax isnt odd.
4. A templating engine gives you extra tools for customizing HTML, such as for loops, if statements, custom filtering, template reuse, inheritance and extensions, etc.
5. I18N, if you happen to need internalization in your project for the HTML content or the HTML tags, using a node library for i18n with a templating engine makes the job super easy (such as node-i18n).

finally, i believe you are new to the frontend world, so this might seem weird to use preprocessors at first, since you can use a templating engine for HTML, a preprocessor for CSS, coffee script or other javascript preprocessors.

I am currently in love with using react or react-like libraries. I would recommend checking react although it might seem a little odd at first, but its beauty relies in writing everything in javascript, from HTML to CSS (inline styles as javascript objects) to javascript itself. you can render it on the server and pass it to the client, plus its super fun to learn and use!

Comment: Hi Ahmad Bamieh .. wow It is a great answer and got a useful idea .now I'm following a tutorial of reactjs.. Thank you so much for answering me ..

Comment: @SarasaGunawardhana glad I could help